# RxJS and Async/Await: How can I compare both?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am a Angular/Ionic developer and recently I got some problems with the Async/Await pattern, resulting on a revaluation on the way that I did things. A friend of mine said that the RxJS library was a great tool to dealt with async calls and so I studied all that the RxJS had to offer.

The thing is, I want to compare both in a equal way that some of my other developer friend can see why RxJS way is better or why it isn't.

To showcase this I made a github repo (https://github.com/gdinn/rxjs-comparative).

I am having some doubts on the async await part. I need to do some concurrent calls and when both are done a loading needs to be dismissed, but without using logic to hold the flux.

The file with both implementations is:
https://github.com/gdinn/rxjs-comparative/blob/master/src/app/home/home.page.ts

Feel free to PR my repo or/and answer here. Both are welcome. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RXJs has some nice things to offer, for example replayable/shareable calls, the piping mechanism for example to map data or merge asynchrounus data, since JavaScript has some issues with retrieving Data, especially Dateformats and Durations, wich often need some sort of Transformation.

The async await style ist really simple but lacks a little bit of "freedom" to intercept/transform asynchrounous retrieved data from a Server (eg Spring), and that leads to a lot of additional code that you need to maintain.

Big contra: The learning curve of RxJs is a little bit annoying, since you create a little bit of spaghetticode when you use excessive piping. But sooner or later complex piping makes more sense and looks less like spaghetticode.

Also the async await pattern, is still there in one or another way, it is just "call and subscribe" but additionaly you have more control over how the Values arrive, how you handle them, how you make dependent asyncrounous calls (aync value A depends on data from async Value B) and how you handle errors , with less boilerplate code.